# Proving $\frac{p_{n+1}^2-p_{n+1}^{-C}}{p_{n+1}^2-1}>\frac{f(n) p_n \log p_n }{p_{n+1} \log p_{n+1}},$ where $f(n)\to1$, for some constant $C>1$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, functional-inequalities

Are there two constants $C_1$, $C_2>1$ such that for large enough $n$ $$\frac{p_{n+1}^2-p_{n+1}^{-C_1}}{p_{n+1}^2-1}>\frac{2 C_2 p_{n+1} \log p_{n+1}-1}{2 C_2 p_{n} \log p_{n}-1} \left(\frac{p_n \log p_n}{p_{n+1} \log p_{n+1}}\right)^n \ \prod_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{p_k^2C_2p_{n+1}\log p_{n+1}-1}{p_k^2C_2p_{n}\log p_{n}-1} \ \ \ \ ?$$

After other attempts (failures), here's what I did to show the thruthfulness of the statement:

Let $m=p_{n+1}$ and set $$\ g(m)>\frac{2 C_2 p_{n+1} \log p_{n+1}-1}{2 C_2 p_{n} \log p_{n}-1} \left(\frac{p_n \log p_n}{p_{n+1} \log p_{n+1}}\right)^{n-1} \ \prod_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{p_k^2C_2p_{n+1}\log p_{n+1}-1}{p_k^2C_2p_{n}\log p_{n}-1} $$ to write the stronger inequality $$\frac{m^2-m^{-C_1}}{m^2-1}>\frac{g(m) (m-2) \log (m-2)}{m \log m},$$ which, since the LHS converges to $1$ strictly from above and, provided that $g(m)\to 1$, clearly the RHS goes to $1$ as well, is implied by $$D\left(\frac{g(m) (m-2) \log (m-2)}{m \log m}\right)>0.$$ This reduces to $$\frac{g'(m)}{g(m)}>\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{m-2} - \frac{1}{(m-2)\log (m-2)}.$$ However I can't see what to do with this to prove the original inequality. How does one proceed? Or how does one prove it with a different approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a go at trying to prove it by simply estimating all the different terms in the equation to find the asymptotic behavior of two sides of the equation. Below $\sim$ will denote an asymptotic value.

Using $p_n\sim n\log n$ we get the following estimates

$$A_n \equiv \frac{p_n\log p_n}{p_{n+1}\log p_{n+1}} \sim 1 - \frac{1}{n}$$

$$B_n \equiv \frac{1}{p_n\log p_n}-\frac{1}{p_{n+1}\log p_{n+1}} \sim \frac{1}{n^2\log^2(n)}$$

Using this we find

$$\frac{2 C_2 p_{n+1} \log p_{n+1}-1}{2 C_2 p_{n} \log p_{n}-1} \sim 1+\frac{B_n}{2C_2} \sim 1+\frac{1}{2C_2n^2\log^2(n)}$$

$$\left(\frac{p_{n}\log p_{n}}{p_{n+1}\log p_{n+1}}\right)^{n-2}\times \prod_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{C_2p_k^2p_{n+1}\log p_{n+1}-1}{C_2p_k^2p_{n}\log p_{n}-1} = \\\prod_{k=2}^{n-1}\left[1 + \frac{B_n}{C_2 p_k^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{p_k^4n^2\log^4 n}\right)\right]\sim 1 + \frac{1}{C_2n^2\log^2 n}\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{p_k^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2\log^4 n}\right)$$

and since $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{p_k^2} < \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ the prefactor to the second term is bounded by a $\mathcal{O}(1)$ constant.

Combinding the results above gives us

$$LHS = 1 + \frac{1-p_{n+1}^{-C_1}}{p_{n+1}^2-1} \sim 1 + \frac{1}{n^2\log^2(n)}$$

for $C_1>0$ and

$$RHS \sim \left(1+\frac{1}{2C_2n^2\log^2(n)}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\left(1 + \frac{\mathcal{O}(1)}{C_2n^2\log^2 n}\right) \sim 1 - \frac{2}{n} + \frac{\mathcal{O}(1)}{C_2 n^2\log^2(n)}$$

and it follows that LHS$-$RHS $ \sim \frac{2}{n} > 0$ for large enough $n$ independent of $C_1,C_2$ (as long as $C_1>0$).

If the $(A_n)^n$ term on the RHS is replaced by $(A_n)^{n-2}$ (removing the middle term in the estimate above) it becomes more interesting as the two sides have comparable convergence to $1$, but by choosing $C_2$ large enough it still follows that LHS$ > $RHS for large enough $n$.

Comment: Nice, thank you! In future I'll write a paper where I use this, can I acknowledge you in it? Also, do you think it is not necessary to "explain" those lines after "we find" and "gives us" in the paper?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Thats not neccesary, but I dont mind it. Just make sure you have gone through all the steps and check that I have not made any mistakes. In a paper you don't need to explain every single step in detail (in some cases to much details can make it harder to read) as long as it is clear what you have done so that people reading it can reproduce it with some work (here imo the statement "using $p_n\sim n\log n$" is enough).

Answer (score 0):

Probably I'm wrong but I hope that this answer could help you.
In this problem I interpreted:
$$1)-p_n\ is\ the\ n-th\ prime\ number$$
$$2)-f(n)\ is\ a\ generic\ sequence\ which\ converges\ to\ 1\ for\ n\ large\ enough$$
$$3)-the\ proposition\ must\ be\ true\ for\ n\ large\ enough$$
Said that,prove that: 
$$\frac{p_{n+1}^2 - p_{n+1}^{-C}}{p_{n+1}^2 - 1} > f(n)\ \frac{p_{n}\ ln(p_{n})}{p_{n+1}\ ln(p_{n+1})}$$
It's equivalent to prove:
$$\frac{p_{n+1}^2 - p_{n+1}^{-C}}{p_{n+1}^2 - 1}\ \frac{p_{n+1}\ ln(p_{n+1})}{p_{n}\ ln(p_{n})} >\ f(n)$$
let's suppose:
$$s(n)\ :=\  \frac{p_{n+1}^2 - p_{n+1}^{-C}}{p_{n+1}^2 - 1}\ \frac{p_{n+1}\ ln(p_{n+1})}{p_{n}\ ln(p_{n})}$$
Then we have:$$s(n) > f(n)$$
It's not difficult to prove that: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}s(n)\ =\ 1\ for\ each\ c>1$$ 
Infact the [Prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) implies that: $$p_n\ \sim\ n\ ln(n)$$
But if we suppose: $$f(n)\ :=\ e^{s(n) - 1}$$
We can verify that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)\ =\ 1 $$
$$ s(n)\ <\ f(n)\ =\ e^{s(n)\ -\ 1}$$
Because: $$ x \le e^{x\ -\ 1}\ with\ x\in\mathbb{R} $$
That should be a contraddiction. 
I'm sorry for the form but it's my first answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for your answer! You're right in what you wrote, aparto from the fact that $f(n)$ is not a generic sequence, it's equal to all that junk you can see in the RHS of my first display in the body of the question. In other words, keep in mind that the inequality in the title and the first displayed one are actually the same.

Comment: Ah ok thanks,now I understand.